# CMB2 Repeatable Group & JSON API

Tags: plugins, api, json

I have problem in API & CMB2 WP plugin

I want to repeat images in slide but api get data as one field

attached photo

Plugin : CMB2, JSON API

https://i.stack.imgur.com/seFsx.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Consider using the CMB2 API.

```
<SITE_URL>/wp-json/cmb2/v1/boxes/<METABOX_ID>/fields/PhotoGalleryGroup?object_id=<POST_ID>&object_type=post
```

You will need to enable the API feature for your box/fields. Documentation for that [is in the wiki](https://github.com/CMB2/CMB2/wiki/REST-API).